# I am not able to create a directory using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a directory using mkdir function in PHP. It works just fine when I am running it on the terminal using `php a.php`, but when I try to run it from the browser as server, I am not able to do it. Why is this?

Comment: What operating system is this running on? What user does the "server" run as?

Comment: i am using Fedora 14 and it is running on httpd server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux is preventing httpd from doing so. See the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the system user your web server is running as doesn't have permission to mkdir. Give the web server process write access by changing the parent directory's owner or group.

Comment: Yes it does. The directory is set 0777.